# Next.JS -> A null PostCSS plugin was provided

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss with Next.JS and getting this error on every first build. It doesn't make any problem but i don't know why i am getting this. Could you please help?

tailwind.css

```
    /* purgecss start ignore */
@tailwind  base;
@tailwind  components;
/* purgecss end ignore */
@tailwind  utilities;
```

postcss.config.js

```
 const purgecss = [
    '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
    {
        // Specify the paths to all of the template files
        content: [
            './layout/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
            './compoents/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
            './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'
        ],
        // This is the function used to extract class names from the templates
        defaultExtractor: (content) => {
            // Capture as liberally as possible, including things like `h-(screen-1.5)`
            const broadMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\\s]*[^<>"'`\\s:]/g) || [];
            // Capture classes within other delimiters like .block(class="w-1/2") in Pug
            const innerMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\\s.()]*[^<>"'`\\s.():]/g) || [];
            return broadMatches.concat(innerMatches);
        },
    },
];
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'tailwindcss',
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? purgecss : undefined,
        'postcss-preset-env',
    ],
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out, I just started having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

[From this article](https://khanna.cc/blog/using-tailwind-ui-and-next-js-together/):

> When you run `npm run dev`, you may get warnings about that a “null PostCSS plugin was provided”. That warning is an artifact of `postcss.config.js` returning `undefined` for instead of PurgeCSS when you are not in production. It can be safely ignored.